# Create new Column based on the data of existing columns

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have an input dataframe with these columns as below:

```
+--------+--------------+----------+-----------+-------+
|sequence|registerNumber|first_name|middle_name|surname|
+--------+--------------+----------+-----------+-------+
|       1|      XXXXXXXX|          |           |       |
|       1|      XXXXXXXX|          |           |       |
|       2|      YYYYYYYY| CAR弟LINE| ELIZABET弟|       |
|       3|      YYYYYYYZ|          |           |  GAL弟|
|       4|      YYYYYYYM| 弟AROLINE|           |       |
|       5|      YYYYYYYL|          |           |       |
```

I want to have a output dataframe like this:

```
+--------+--------------+----------+-----------+-------+------------
|sequence|registerNumber|first_name|middle_name|surname|errorColumn
+--------+--------------+----------+-----------+-------+-----------
|       1|      XXXXXXXX|          |           |       |
|       1|      XXXXXXXX|          |           |       |
|       2|      YYYYYYYY| CAR弟LINE| ELIZABET弟 |       |first_name-middle_name
|       3|      YYYYYYYZ|          |           |  GAL弟|surname
|       4|      YYYYYYYM| 弟AROLINE|           |       |first_name
|       5|      YYYYYYYL|          |           |       |
```

The `errorColumn` should contain the column names`(first_name, middle_name, surname)` which aren't empty with a separator as `-` whenever there's value in 2 or more fields

I am trying to do this for list of columns and tried to do this using `concat` but the performance is poor.

Comment: are they empty string or null?

Comment: @Emma they are empty string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `concat_ws` and `when` and collect only when character length is more than 0 (not empty string).

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

cols = ['first_name', 'middle_name', 'surname']

df = (df.withColumn("error_column", 
                    F.concat_ws('-', 
                                *[F.when(F.length(F.col(x)) > 0, F.lit(x)) 
                                  for x in cols])))
```